# Data alignment inside a structure in Intel Fortran

Tags: fortran, vectorization, memory-alignment, intel-fortran

I'm trying to align in memory the following type of data:

```
type foo
   real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: bar1, bar2
   !dir$ attributes align:64 :: bar1
   !dir$ attributes align:64 :: bar2
end type foo

type(foo), allocatable, dimension(:) :: my_foo
allocate(my_foo(1))
allocate(my_foo(1)%bar1(100))
allocate(my_foo(1)%bar2(100))

! somewhere here I need to tell the compiler that data is aligned
!    for a simple array with name `bar` I would just do:
!dir$ assume_aligned bar1: 64
!dir$ assume_aligned bar2: 64
!    but what do I do for the data type I have, something like this?
!dir$ assume_aligned my_foo(1)%bar1: 64
!dir$ assume_aligned my_foo(1)%bar2: 64

do i = 1, 100
   my_foo(1)%bar1(i) = 10.
   my_foo(1)%bar2(i) = 10.
end do
```

As you can see, it's an array of `foo` type structures, that has two large arrays `bar1` and `bar2` as variables that I need to be aligned near cache boundaries in the memory.

I kind of know how to do that for simple arrays ([link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/data-alignment-to-assist-vectorization)), but I have no idea how to do that for this sort of complex data structure. And what if `my_foo` wasn't of size 1, but was of size, say, 100? Do I loop through them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, case semi-closed. The solution turned out to be pretty straightforward. You just use pointers and do an `assume_aligned` to them. That should take care of it.

```
type foo
   real, allocatable, dimension(:) :: bar1, bar2
   !dir$ attributes align:64 :: bar1
   !dir$ attributes align:64 :: bar2
end type foo

type(foo), target, allocatable, dimension(:) :: my_foo
real, pointer, contiguous :: pt_bar1(:)
real, pointer, contiguous :: pt_bar2(:)
allocate(my_foo(1))
allocate(my_foo(1)%bar1(100))
allocate(my_foo(1)%bar2(100))

pt_bar1 = my_foo(1)%bar1
pt_bar2 = my_foo(1)%bar2
!dir$ assume_aligned pt_bar1:64, pt_bar2:64

pt_bar1 = 10.
pt_bar2 = 10.
```

`do` loops are still not vectorized smh. Like if I do the same thing like this

```
do i = 1, 100
   pt_bar1(i) = 10.
   pt_bar2(i) = 10.
end do
```

it won't be vectorized.

**UPD.**
Ok, this does the job (also need to add `-qopenmp-simd` flag to the compiler):

```
!$omp simd
!dir$ vector aligned
do i = 1, 100
   pt_bar1(i) = 10.
   pt_bar2(i) = 10.
end do
```

Also if you're looping through `my_foo(j)%...` make sure to free the pointers after each iteration with `pt_bar1 => null()` etc.

PS. Thanks to BW from our department for this help. :) Sometimes personal communication > stackoverflow (not always, only sometimes).

Comment: What do you want to vectorize in that loop? It is a memory store operation, not a mathematical computation.

Comment: I just want to vectorize the `do` loop. If I write an implicit loop like this `pt_bar = 10` it vectorizes, but when I do an explicit loop `do i=1,100 ...`, it doesn't.